# How to store custom data against a product

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, attributes

I have a bunch of data I need to store against a product when importing from another system. These can be things like `Arm Length`, `SomeOther Property`.

What is the best way to store this information in Magento based on the fact I need to:

1. Be able to update the values regularly (the products will be re-imported to update them).
2. Be able to see the values in the product section in Magento.

Initially I tried creating a group called `My Options` against the default Attribute Set and adding each of my options as an attribute against that group however, if I need to add more attributes to a product, adding them to the `My Options` section in the Default set doesn't add them to the existing product.

Can anyone offer some advice please?

Comment: Are you using Magmi?

Comment: Sorry, what is Magmi? (That would be a No though I guess).

Comment: [Magmi](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Magmi_Wiki) is a super-useful tool to import products, and could help you with your attribute problem.

More questions: are the attributes not showing on the product in the front-end or back-end? Is your "my options" group showing up on those products in the backend?

Comment: Ok, well no I am not. All I need to know is how to store this information. I can work the code out from that.

Comment: I believe he asks about magmi because if you create the new attribute and place it in your attribute set, it should 'create' but not 'assign a value for' that attribute to existing products. Then you could use magmi to do mass updates of the new attributes to existing products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added a section against the default attribute set and added all my options to that. On import, I then add any new ones and just update the product attributes like I would normally.

The key is adding the attributes before doing the stock import (or at least before saving the product).

This seems to work well for me.